# A word describing how 'profound I am in a skill': Can you suggest one?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am in the process of localizing an application and I can't wrap my head around a specific translation.

The user can enter a skill / prof. experience they have acquired or a language they speak besides their native tongue.

Example:

The user is is born somewhere in Britain and is a native English speaker. He also speaks French and enters "French" as a language skill. In a second step he is asked how proficient/good/experienced he is in this language, ranging from basic knowledge (1) up to fluid speaking (5).

I am looking for a terminology describing how profound a person is in a chosen skillset, like (basic/good/fluid/native tongue). A word which describes how well versed somebody a person in something.

Looking in the dictionary and several online translation sources I narrowed it down to:

- Characteristic
- Profoundness
- Degree
- Peculiarity

In my opinion, in my ears "degree" sounds best, but I am not 100% happy with it. If it helps you, the native word we use in German is "Ausprägung".

Comment: *Proficiency* perhaps. It's hard to tell exactly what you want though with just words out of context (considering that you aren't happy with those words, yourself). Could you show a sentence that attempts to use it?

Comment: It's not used in a sentence, but as a label for a dropdown box, where a user can choose how proficient he is in a skill.

Comment: So, what are the choices in the drop-down?

Comment: It depends on whether we are talking about language, professional experience or anything else. In general it is a scale from 1-5 where 5 is the highest rating you can give yourself in anything.

Comment: What does 'The user can enter a skill / prof. experience' mean?

Comment: There are no guys at UI. There is an in house client, who wants something and does not want to pay a professional translator.
I'll get blamed once it goes live.

Comment: @Stephie As a last comment: Yes it's requested by the client. I am usually only responsible for the technical side of things. Generating content isn't my field of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Proficiency*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proficiency), the degree to which someone is proficient in something.

Answer (score 1):

- while *proficiency* is the "correct" term,
- *level* is frequently used in these drop-down boxes, too.

Comment: The *level* refers to the level of proficiency.